# Ajax does not receive data on second call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

i am making a calendar, and i make an ajax request on page load to get the some data from the rails db.

the ajax call successfully receives object on page load.

when i click on next or previous button to get the previous months data or next months data, even though the ajax call happens, no data object is receiving on success callback

i receive a set of objects which i access like the code below but only for the *page load ajax call*, the ajax call gets a status code 200 - OK each time but no json object is received on next requests.

**In other words, console.log(data) only works on the page load event while console.log($month) works everytime**

UPDATE: using the dev tools, i can see the response data, but they are not accessible from success in ajax...

UPDATE 2: when i uncomment error i get the message "The error code is: OK"

my ajax code looks like this

```
function retrieve($month) {

    console.log($month);
    var jsondata = {
      events: {
        month: $month,
      }
    }
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: "POST",
      url: "/events/find",
      data: jsondata,
      dataType: json,

      statusCode: {

        200: function() {
          //alert("200");
        },
        202: function() {
          //alert("202");
        }
      },
      success: function(data) {
        //alert("Data Send!");
        //var data = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var day = data[i].date.substring(0, 2);
          $("td[data-day='" + day + "']").addClass('added');
        }

      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        //alert("The error code is: " + xhr.statusText);
      }
    });
  }
```

events_controller

```
def find
    params = event_params

    @events = Event.where('date LIKE ?',"%#{params[:month]}%")

    respond_to do |format|
      if @events
        format.json {
          render json: @events.to_json
        }
      else
        render 'index'
      end
    end
  end

private
    def event_params
      params.require(:events).permit(:date, :timerange,:month)
    end
```

example response from rails log

```
Started POST "/events/find" for ::1 at 2015-08-16 16:09:59 +0300
Processing by EventsController#find as */*
  Parameters: {"events"=>{"month"=>"September"}}
  Event Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (date LIKE '%September%')
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax works only on page load - (jQuery and rails)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035142/ajax-works-only-on-page-load-jquery-and-rails)

Comment: Please delete your previous question, or edit it if you have refined it. This appears to be the same question asked in a different way.

Comment: closed the other one. this is more clear.

Comment: what is the exact console output (if you have any) when you go next/previous? Did you try to debug the call in developer tools??

Comment: i receive a set of objects which i access like the code above but only for the page load ajax call, the ajax call gets a status code 200 - OK each time but no json object is received on next requests. In other words, console.log(data) only works on the page load event while console.log($month) works everytime

Answer (score 2):

Just for future reference for someone who might need this.

The problem was the `dataType: json`

it seems that when rails converted the results to json, they were invalid for jquery thus the error event was fired.

removing dataType.json from the ajax request fixed my problems.

Comment: jQuery always do an intelligent guess for `datatype` if not set explicitly, nice to bring in notice. :)

Comment: yeah well i am mad with rails for not properly converting object to json ;p